# converting AP from autonomous to CAPWAP; DHCP keeps interrupting TFTP Process (follow up)

Tags: cisco, ipv4, dhcp, access-point, tftp

This question is actually a follow up to this link:

[converting AP from CAPWAP to autonomous - BVI1 interface gets reverted back to DHCP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/converting-ap-from-capwap-to-autonomous-bvi1-interface-gets-reverted-back-to-d?newreg=0a78155a09b6469daba9ee5a9b51e9be)

The method I tried to follow:

```
AP#debug capwap console cli   
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7#enable
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7#conf t
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7(config)#ip default-gateway 10.10.10.1
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7(config)#int bvi1
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7(config-if)#ip address 10.10.10.102 255.255.255.0
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7(config-if)#no shut
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7(config-if)#end
AP5475.d0f5.2ee7#copy tftp://10.10.10.103/ap3g2-k9w8-tar.152-2.jb.tar flash:
```

Then my TFTP gets interrupted during 75% of the transferred with the prompt. “Could not discover WLC. Either IP address is not assigned or assigned IP is wrong. Renewing DHCP.”

I made sure to change my PC IP address as `10.10.10.103 255.255.255.0` with default-gateway as `10.10.10.1` and a preferred DNS as `10.10.10.1`.

The path of my firmware is `C:\tftpd64.400\ap3g2-k9w8-tar.152-2.jb.tar`.

Please help.

Comment: Do you try to convert from autonomous to lightweight (as your title say) or the reverse (as the linked issue say)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This looks similar to [converting AP from CAPWAP to autonomous - BVI1 interface gets reverted back to DHCP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/converting-ap-from-capwap-to-autonomous-bvi1-interface-gets-reverted-back-to-d)

`debug capwap client no-reload` should prevent the AP from reloading when no DHCP is detected and/or CAPWAP can't join the controller.